# qemu-i386 on ARM processor giving ld-linux.so.2 error

Tags: linux, emulation, qemu, ventrilo

I am trying to install Ventrilo server on my SheevaPlug, running Debian ARMEL.  Since Ventrilo  server is an x86 program, I would like to try and use qemu-i386 to run the server on my ARM processor.  I am running into this error when I try to run the server:

```
ventrilo@micro:~/ventsrv$ qemu-i386 ./ventrilo_srv
/lib/ld-linux.so.2: No such file or directory
```

I understand that /lib/ld-linux.so.2 is the x86 version of the so, and so.3 is the ARM version (which I have).  Do I just find the so.2 shared object and put it in my /lib folder?  Seems like I wouldn't want to mix lib archs in that folder, but maybe that's why they're named differently?  How should I resolve this error?

Comment: So, I tried to just copy the .so.2 over and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved on my ARM device by copying my PC i386 ***ld-linux.so.2*** as below :

```
scp /lib/ld-linux.so.2 root@192.168.109.X:/lib
```

and then by copying all the needed shared libraries. In my case, I've organized all of them in a new folder inside my device before copying them :

```
mkdir /lib/i386-linux-gnu
scp /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 [device]:/lib/i386-linux-gnu
scp /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 [device]:/lib/i386-linux-gnu
scp /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [device]:/lib/i386-linux-gnu
scp /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 [device]:/lib/i386-linux-gnu
```